# count of the multiple values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I have a dictionary like the one below and I want to find out how many of the values in it are from the value entered by the user.

```
{'a': ['Sun', 'Jack'], 'b': ['John', 'Sun', 'Sarah'],...
```

Count how many `'Sun'` in dictionary

Expected output: `2`

Comment: Can you add your code attempts? This sounds very much like a homework style question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum`.

```
dct = {'a': ['Sun'], 'b': ['John', 'Sun', 'Sarah']}
res = sum('Sun' in lst for lst in dct.values())
print(res)
# 2
```

Comment: I have one more question.

Now I found out how many times they repeat. Now I want to find the key values of those who only have one, for example 'John'.

Comment: @poe41, Do you want key of `John`? Do you want return `b`

Comment: return b If there's only one from 'John'

Comment: @poe41, Try this: `if sum('John' in lst for lst in dct.values()) == 1:
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if 'John' in v:
            print(k)`

Comment: I'm stuck somewhere else. I have 2 dictionaries, one {'a': ['Sun'], 'b': ['John', 'Sun', 'Sarah']} and the other {'a': 100, 'b': 80, 'c': 90 } Printing the key and value values of the 'Sun' in the first dictionary and the higher value in the second dictionary.
so the expected output for 'Sun' is: a,100

Comment: @poe41, in the above code, find key when the value is equal to 'Sun', then find value in `dict2` base key tht you find.  ```dct = {'a': ['Sun'], 'b': ['John', 'Sun', 'Sarah']} 
dct2 = {'a': 100, 'b': 80, 'c': 90 }
for k,v in dct.items():         
    if 'Sun' in v:             
        print(k , dct2[k])```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way is to go through each value of the dict

```py
dictionary = {'a': ['Sun', 'Jack'], 'b': ['John', 'Sun', 'Sarah']}
count = 0
for key in dictionary:
  if 'Sun' in dictionary[key]:
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: I'm stuck somewhere else. I have 2 dictionaries, one {'a': ['Sun'], 'b': ['John', 'Sun', 'Sarah']} and the other {'a': 100, 'b': 80, 'c': 90 } Printing the key and value values of the 'Sun' in the first dictionary and the higher value in the second dictionary. so the expected output for 'Sun' is: a,100

Answer (score 0):

Chain the all values of the dictionary with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, and then count with `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> mapping = {'a': ['Sun', 'Jack'], 'b': ['John', 'Sun', 'Sarah']}
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(mapping.values()))['Sun']
2
```

**Update:**

For the new question you posted in the comment section:

```
>>> mp1 = {'a'：['Sun']，'b'：['John'，'Sun'，'Sarah']}
>>> mp2 = {'a'：100，'b'：80，'c'：90 }
>>> keys = (k for k, v in mp1.items() if 'Sun' in v)
>>> max_key = max(keys, key=mp2.__getitem__)
>>> max_key, mp2[max_key]
('a', 100)
```

Comment: I'm stuck somewhere else. I have 2 dictionaries, one {'a': ['Sun'], 'b': ['John', 'Sun', 'Sarah']} and the other {'a': 100, 'b': 80, 'c': 90 } Printing the key and value values of the 'Sun' in the first dictionary and the higher value in the second dictionary. so the expected output for 'Sun' is: a,100